# Writing multiple fields (struct) to fifo

Tags: c, linux, struct, fifo

I Need to write the following struct to a fifo:

```
struct msg_t {
   int length;
   char* msg;
};
```

I malloc the struct and the char* inside it and I write like this:
(let's assume msg is the variable name)
write(fifo_fd, &msg, sizeof(msg_t));

The length is read from the other end just fine.
The string isn't..
How can I write those two fields with a single write?
If not, are two separate writes good?

Thank you.

Comment: For clarity include some code of what you're trying to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will just be writing the length and the pointer address, which I doubt is what you will want at the other end. My guess is what you actually want is something like this:

```
struct msg_t msg;
// Initialise msg
write( fifo_fd, &(msg.length), sizeof(int) );
write( fifo_fd, msg.msg, msg.length );
```

Comment: Thank you.. That's what I thought of but, I thought there was a way to do this in one write.
I guess this is the most correct way :)

Comment: @dlv There *are* ways to do it in one write, but it takes some prep-work on the data storage side. Honestly, it isn't work the hassle if this is all you want done. This answer will do what you need. (+1, btw).

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using [flexible array members](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) (also explained [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzarg/flexible.htm))? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680946/allocating-struct-with-flexible-array-member)... So declare

```
struct msg_t {
    unsigned length;
    char msg[];
};
```

allocate it with e.g.

```
struct msg_t* make_msg(unsigned l) {
  // one extra byte for the terminating null char
  struct msg_t* m = malloc(sizeof(struct msg_t)+l+1; 
  if (!m) { perror("malloc m"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  memset(m, 0, sizeof(struct msg_t)+l+1);
  m->length = l;
  return m;
}
```

then write it with e.g.

```
fwrite(m, sizeof(struct msg_t)+m->length+1, 1, fil);
```

or if you use `write` do the buffering yourself (since a `write` can be partial!) e.g.

```
void write_msg(int fd, struct msg_t *m) {
   assert(m != NULL);
   char* b = m;
   unsigned siz = sizeof(struct msg_t)+m->length+1);
   while (siz>0) {
      int cnt=write (fd, b, siz);
      if (cnt<0) { perror("write"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
      b += cnt;
      siz -= cnt;
   }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why using `unsigned` but `size_t` for `length`?